# Why does Review "Suggested-Edits" counter keep displaying even if I am not allowed to review?

Tags: feature-request, bug, review-queues

Today I made an incorrect review, so I can't review in the next two days, this is not the problem here:

I am wondering why would the Suggested Edits counter in the top bar keep displaying even if I made a mistake and I am not allowed to review within the 2 days.

[image: Review Counter]

Why would I get notified for Pending suggested Edits, and have a link to Review Task section if I am not allowed to Review?

[image]

Isn't that a bug that should be fixed?

So the purpose is that people who are not allowed **temporarily** to review don't get notified?

Comment: +1 for managing to fail a suggested edit audit. I didn't actually believe that was possible.

Comment: Actually **it's**, we are human after all.

Comment: It is even worse when on a smaller site and you suggest a tag wiki edit and you see the counter displayed for the edit you just suggested.

Comment: @JoeW Yes indeed.

Comment: @JonasCz Why whould be marked as a duplicate of this suggested question, when it has no answers and whouldn't help much??

Comment: because it is effectively the same feature request, of "make this notification something personalised to the user"?

Answer (score 2):

Because the number is cached across *all users*, it's probably not worth it (read: computationally expensive) to introduce a check and see if you're actually entitled to review each item and provide an individual count to every user.

You still get this display even when you've used all 20 reviews in a day as well. Or when the only pending edits are ones you yourself have suggested. It's just the way it is.

Comment: Actually the number is cached for all users but the top bar is personal and every user should have **only** its relevant information showed, so the check can easily be done, if you can do it in the review page nothing whould prevent you from doing it in other pages.

Comment: It's done on the review page when you specifically request that information. Doing it on every single page view is disproportionate.

Comment: Actually, it's only an attribute in the user table which will be added and changed whenever this one makes a mistake, and a given class will be used to hide this notification automatically, so the check doesn't cost too much.

Comment: What benefit do you see from this? If you know you are banned from reviewing, just don't pay attention to the number. The check may not cost much from your point of view, but scaled out across the thousands of users viewing Stack Exchange sites at any one time it all adds up. There is presumably a reason they've designed it how it is, and resisted requests to change it up to now.

Comment: It's only an ergonomic issue here, that's the benifit.